# Appending more complex HTML elements using JS in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my chrome extension to add some HTML elements to a currently existing page I don't administrate.
I'm using JavaScript with no libraries due to system limitations.

I've currently successfully implemented 3 buttons using createElement() + appendChild().

I now want to add a multi level dropdown menu and my current method of adding elements gets very messy very quickly since I have to add all the HTML properties like this:

```
elementToAdd.id = "btnENG";
elementToADd.innerText = "Button English";
```

This is not viable for a multi element "ul" "li" dropdown menu since my code quickly becomes illegible (maybe due to my own syntax).

How would one create a complex HTML element or block and append it to an existing page using JS from a Chrome Extension?

Is insertAdjacentHTML good practice?

Is there a way I can add an HTML file to my extension's manifest.json file and summon an HTML element from that file with JS to be appended on the website?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: If there's a lot of html with complex css/js it may be best to put it inside a separate html file (ui.html), expose it in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/), add an iframe in your content script with `src` pointing to chrome.runtime.getURL('ui.html')